# Should this python syntax be valid?

Tags: python, syntax, annotations, programming-languages, type-hinting

I recently noticed that the following syntax is valid in python:

```py
d = {}
d['non_existent']: int
```

But `d['non_existent']`, even if present, would translate to a value, which can't be annotated as these examples show:

```py
3: int
f(): str
```

Both raise `SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation`.

So why will the above syntax be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the associated documents with annotations, I found that, in fact, expressions can be annotated and is up to the checker whether to use them or not: https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#annotating-expressions
Although, it looks like mypy is not working with this because on that example it throws `Unexpected type declaration`.

Comment: "expression" is the wrong word here; after all, `3` and `f()` are expressions.